# Machine learning Multi label text classification using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-mining, modeling, text-classification

I am building an machine learning text classification model in R. I want to classify the sentence into more than one label if it falls into multiple categories.

e.g.: "The phone screen resolution is awesome and the battery life as well" - currently I am able to classify the sentence into either Battery or Phone feature category but I want it to be classified into both.

The output can be like:
[image]

It will be great if anyone can help me with ideas or methods to get the above result.

Comment: How are your categories defined? Do you you use a dictionary? Or do you want to use a probabilistic (unsupervised) classification? The latter will, however, not necessarily produce categories in a way that you desire. There are plenty of packages for text mining that might be relevant on [CRAN Task View: Natural Language Processing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have historically classified data for building supervised model. Currently I am using RTexttool package by creating a container and using train_models and classify_models methods.Please can you help me with the methods or example links for multi label classification

Comment: If you have already tried something it would be helpful to provide the code with some data to have a reproducible example.

Comment: One approach is to build a classification model for each class, then set a threshold and assign any class above the threshold to the text.

Comment: Below is the code I have written for model building: 
    'corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))'
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))

     comments <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
    container <- create_container(comments, x.rand$V1,    trainSize=1:568,testSize=569:710, virgin=FALSE)
    model <- train_model(container, algorithms=c("SVM"),kernel='linear')
    results <- classify_model(container, model)

Comment: Thanks Lan Wesley, I will try your suggestion by classifying the model for each class/theme and set a threshold for it. Will update you once completed. Thank you :)

Comment: Hey, have you reached any solution? if yes, can you please share that?

Comment: I tried a very simple method i.e. the predict function with type='prob' which gave the probabilities for all the themes and using threshold value just tried multi classification.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest training a binary classifier for each label.

With some algorithms - like logistic regression - all you can do is train every binary classifier independently.

There are also so-called multilabel algorithms - they train all binary classifiers at the same time, and extract the same features from data for every classifier. An example is a neural network with a sigmoid last layer. See "support multilabel" section in http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html for a list of multilabel algorithms.

Of course, a multilabel algorithm will not necessarily outperform logistic regression, you have to try and see what works best for your problem.

Comment: thanks seed, currently I am using SVM algorithm for training the model. I will try binary classifiers and update you. Thank you :)